# SQL QUERY for showing students where they born in 1993, 11

Tags: sql

I have task from my school

Please show the name of students where they were born in 1993 month 11

```
select 
    x.[5_name] 
from
    [5Student] x, [5Birthday] y 
where 
    YEAR(y.[5_date]) = '1993' 
    and MONTH(y.[5_date]) = '11' 
    and x.[5_nim] = y.[5_student]
```

If you have another way for solved the query, please share here

*may that code important for someone

Comment: Why is birthday in a separate table? What is the datatype of `[5_date]`?

Comment: There is no other way in your other than joining two tables. It would've been another case if you put these two fields in one table

Answer (score 3):

Your current `WHERE` clause is unsargable. Rewriting as a range query

```
WHERE y.[5_date] >= { d '1993-11-01' } AND  y.[5_date] < { d '1993-12-01' }
```

means an index can be used.

Comment: thank you. this query will show they having born in 1993 from month 11 until 12.

Comment: WHERE y.[5_date] >= { d '1993-11-01' } AND  y.[5_date] < { d '1993-11-31' }

Comment: @Man - November only has 30 days. I use `< '1993-12-01'` instead of `<= '1993-11-30'` in case there is any time component (which there shouldn't be for a birthday but you haven't told us what datatype you are using)

Answer (score 2):

You're not saying what **database engine** you use (SQL = structured query language - just the language, not a product) - but I would recommend to *always* use the new ANSI Standard `JOIN` syntax (instead of just listing a comma-separated list of tables to use):

```
select 
    x.[5_name] 
from
    [5Student] x
inner join
    [5Birthday] y ON x.[5_nim] = y.[5_student]
where 
    YEAR(y.[5_date]) = '1993' 
    and MONTH(y.[5_date]) = '11'
```

Makes it clearer what you join, and moves the `JOIN` condition where it belongs - to the `JOIN` statement (and doesn't mess up the `WHERE` condition with `JOIN` conditions).

Pretty much any decent database engine these days **ought to support this**.

Comment: for this task, we can't to use query like INNER JOIN. do you have other way ?

Comment: @Man: and ***why not***?!?!?

Comment: @Man: tell your teacher he should teach your **proper** SQL according to ANSI/ISO standards ...

Comment: Hehehe... Be calm @marc_s. I was going to tell you that his teacher will get angry. Many teachers specially at school level get angry if student presents something about teacher did not tell and if teacher even did not know then,, O My God.... :D

Comment: @Sami: yeah - but those teachers are the ones "producing" all those developers who can't even properly write SQL in their day job ..... (sorry - pet peeve of mine...)

Comment: :) Yes true. I am bachelor and currently jobless just due to my laziness but I am not choosing teaching just because I think when I am not with my development skills then why should I teach. (sorry - all SE teachers) :)